# Channel Entries tag pair not populating in the view template

Tags: expressionengine

I have a working template that is included in the right rail of my EE site.

This template pulls from a channel that simply relates entries from other channels to this specific channel on a one-to-one basis and is used as a sort of "highlight reel" or "Top 5" for the sidebar. The relationship is using Playa to link multiple different channel's entries to this one.

It works throughout the site with exception to an entry's view template. In that template it only returns with highlighted entries that match that channel. I am simply using the same embed code for another template that is embedded into every page. It embeds like:

```
index <- right_rail <- highlight_reel
```

For example, the highlight reel can pull from Activities, Events, and Food channels using Playa for the relationship. When you navigate to the view template of a particular Events entry this only displays Events entries that have been related.

Is there a configuration or parameter that needs to be set in order to keep the results consistent?

*Let me know if there is anything else that would help you help me.*

Some additional code for the loop:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="most_popular" dynamic="yes" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="5"} 
    {exp:playa:children field="popular_entry" status="not closed" disable="members" limit="1"}
```

**Thanks a bundle in advance!**

Comment: Can you show us the code?  First guess: dynamic="off"

Comment: @AllInOne : I've revised the details to include the setup for the loop. It seems to behave properly everywhere but the view template :(

Comment: Oh I've found a working answer to this!

Answering this post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was directed to [a similar question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/25206/related-entries-using-playa) that was asked and it totally solved the issue.

My mistake was that I had assumed that it would maintain the entry_id but by embedding it I was able to solve it.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Great!  You should accept your own answer so this question doesn't show up as "unanswered".